# Stop GUI squishing up when keyboard appears?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gui

I just want my GUI elements to stay where they are.

Instead, whenever the keyboard comes up, they push half the labels and buttons up.

I'm using relative layout if it helps.

I've tried adding things like:

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

to the manifest.xml but it hasn't done anything.

Ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

```
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

in the onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in EditText component in layout.xml if you use scroll,

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
```